# find value in array mongoose+typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have an schema created with mongoose+typescript like this :

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Types, Document } from 'mongoose'
import { mongoosePagination, Pagination } from 'mongoose-paginate-ts'
import { Department } from './departmentModel'
import { Designation } from './designationModel'
import { Roles } from './roleModel'

export interface IEmployee extends Document {
  userName: string
  email: string
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  designation: Types.ObjectId
  department: [Types.ObjectId]
  roles: [Types.ObjectId]
  projects: string
  status: string
  reportingManager: [
    {
      managerId: string
      userName: string
    },
  ]
  approver: [
    {
      approverId: string
      userName: string
    },
  ]
  createdBy: string
  updatedBy: string
}

type employeeUser = mongoose.Document & {
  userName: string
  email: string
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  designation: Types.ObjectId
  department: [Types.ObjectId]
  roles: [Types.ObjectId]
  projects: string
  status: string
  reportingManager: [
    {
      managerId: string
      userName: string
    },
  ]
  approver: [
    {
      approverId: string
      userName: string
    },
  ]
  createdBy: string
  updatedBy: string
}

const schema = new Schema(
  {
    userName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    designation: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: Designation,
      required: true,
    },
    department: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: Department,
      required: true,
    }],
    roles: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: Roles,
        required: true,
      },
    ],
    status: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
      required: true,
    },
    reportingManager: [
      {
        managerId: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        userName: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    approver: [
      {
        approverId: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        userName: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    createdBy: {
      type: String,
      immutable: true,
    },
    updatedBy: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { collection: 'user', timestamps: true },
)
schema.plugin(mongoosePagination)
const User: Pagination<IEmployee> = mongoose.model<employeeUser, Pagination<IEmployee>>('User', schema)
export { User }
```

And trying using like this::

```
 import { IEmployee, User } from '@/models/user'    

const getEmployeeDetailsHelper = async (paginationQuery: unknown): Promise<unknown> => {
  try {
    return await User.find({department: '623aca76efa7cf01ec7c39ac'}).exec()
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(JSON.stringify(err))
    return err
  }
}
```

but typescript giving me error like:

```
  No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(callback?: Callback<IEmployee[]>): Query<IEmployee[], IEmployee, {}, IEmployee>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ department: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback<IEmployee[]>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'department' does not exist in type 'Callback<IEmployee[]>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(filter: FilterQuery<IEmployee>, callback?: Callback<IEmployee[]>): Query<IEmployee[], IEmployee, {}, IEmployee>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Condition<[ObjectId]>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(filter: FilterQuery<IEmployee>, projection?: any, options?: QueryOptions, callback?: Callback<IEmployee[]>): Query<IEmployee[], IEmployee, {}, IEmployee>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Condition<[ObjectId]>'.ts(2769)
user.ts(13, 3): The expected type comes from property 'department' which is declared here on type 'FilterQuery<IEmployee>'
user.ts(13, 3): The expected type comes from property 'department' which is declared here on type 'FilterQuery<IEmployee>'
```

Please help.

Comment: department is defined as an array of ObjectIDs, but you are trying to pass a string as a value.